# How correctly define the pixel intensity of an image?

Tags: notation, image-processing

Let's do easy:
I have an image IM and p(i,j) is the discrete intensity value of a pixel in the image IM (not necessarily 2-dimensional)..... How can I mathematically correctly define this?
Thank you so much!

Comment: http://enthdegree.tumblr.com/post/102480374444/a-model-for-image-capture

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you exactly mean by "intensity". I suggest you familiarize yourself with different [color models](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) and the difference between [additive](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) and [subtractive](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color) colors.

After this (probably too generic) answer, I'll give it a shot, whilst making some assumptions:

- You're talking additive colorspace
- You mean how "bright" a pixel shines, regardless of its color.
- You want to calculate this "intensity" based on the RGB values of the image.

In that case, you'll find the [HSL and/or HSV](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (Hue, Saturation and Lightness/Value, which are slightly different!) colorspaces useful. Check the link - it contains a lot of good information. I'll cite the lightness, value and intensity definitions from that page:

> **Brightness**: The "attribute of a visual sensation according to which an
>   area appears to emit more or less light".
>
> **Lightness or Value**: The
>   "brightness relative to the brightness of a similarly illuminated
>   white".

Now, to the concretely answer of your question, in mathematical terms:

- Value = max( R, G, B )
- Lightness = 1/2 * max( R, G, B ) + 1/2 * min( R, G, B )

Where R, G and B are the values of a pixel in Red, Green and Blue colorspace.

Please refer to the previously mentioned link about HSV and HSB for a more elaborate explanation and some [second thoughts](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV%23Disadvantages).